# "unmet dependencies: python3-click-package" when attempting click install

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-touch, dependencies, 16.10

I am attempting to install Click and other tools on Ubuntu 16.10 for managing an Ubuntu phone. Specifically, I wish to install the packages `click` and `phablet-tools`. When I attempt to do this, I get the following terminal output:

```
>sudo apt-get -y install python3-click-package
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-click-package : Depends: gir1.2-click-0.4 (= 0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have run the following commands but I continue to see the problem:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: try  `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: please try this `sudo apt -f install python3-click-package`, if it fails try `sudo apt -f install gir1.2-click-0.4` then the former

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As told here [16.04 click unmet dependancies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927309/16-04-click-unmet-dependancies) execute the command.

```
sudo apt install python3-click-package=0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2 gir1.2-click-0.4=0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2 libclick-0.4-0=0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2
```