# 16.04 click unmet dependancies

Tags: 16.04, package-management, dependencies, click-packages

I am in a situation where package click is broken. I have tried many things, but did not manage to fix it.

```
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 click : Depends: python3-click-package (= 0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2) but 0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Obvioulsy `sudo apt-get -f install` does not fix it. Nor trying to remove `python3-click-package`.

Any help welcomed.

```
$ apt-cache policy click python3-click-package
click:
  Installed: 0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2 500
    500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
python3-click-package:
  Installed: 0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

I can not even remove the package:

```
$sudo apt-get -f purge click
The following packages will be REMOVED
  click*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed. 
After this operation, 88.1 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
(Reading database ... 590369 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing click (0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 55, in <module>
    from click import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'
dpkg: error processing package click (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Job for click-system-hooks.service failed because the control process     exited with error code. See "systemctl status click-system-hooks.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
click-system-hooks.service couldn't start.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 click
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy click python3-click-package`?

Comment: Looks like you disabled the xenial-updates repo. Enable it.

Comment: xenial-updates is enabled.

Comment: Updated post with apt-cache policy output.

Comment: What if you simply run `sudo apt install click`?

Comment: If I try to install, it tries to upgrade it and fails with the same error.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error exactly? It seems like an upgrade of the `click` package is what's needed, since the packages it depends on are already upgraded.

Answer (score 4):

Managed to sort it out with:

```
sudo apt install python3-click-package=0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2 gir1.2-click-0.4=0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2 libclick-0.4-0=0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2
```

I built that command step by step following the messages in the unmet dependencies...
Then I was able to fully remove the click package...

```
sudo apt purge click
```

Comment: Does not seem to work. I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove the file `/usr/bin/click` first to make `sudo apt-get purge click`work again. After that i installed click via pip.